# Can I turn off Windows Search service?

Tags: windows, windows-search

can I turn off Windows Search service? It takes plenty of my computer resources. Can I set up like like manually running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Start > Run > Services.msc

Scroll down to 'Windows Search' and right-click. From Properties, change the 'Startup type' to Manual.